# Faulty P-CH MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, fet

Last month I bought a couple of [IRF5305](http://www.redrok.com/MOSFET_IRF5305_-55V_-31A_6mO_Vth-4.0_TO-220.pdf) (click for datasheet) on Ebay. Today I soldered a couple of them in my PCB and had some issues with them. My FET schematic looks like the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcZvfQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

According to the datasheet the gate-source threshold voltage lies somewhere between 2V and 4V. Now when I put logic '1' on the gate the gate-source voltage is around 1.7V. In this situation I would expect that the MOSFET will not conduct. However, in practice it did conduct and I could even power a small blue LED as load.

Now I played a little bit with the voltage on the gate, and it seems to be turned off once I put around 3.8V on the gate. So right now I'm guessing that either I'm doing something wrong, or that these 'chinese' MOSFETS are out of spec. I hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: You do realize that this is a P-channel MOSFET?

Comment: It seems simple, if you don't want it to conduct, pull up to 5v. Although this will require 5v tolerant IO.

Comment: Don't blame the MOSFET. this is a PEBCAB.

Comment: In industry, everybody knows that Vgs has to be zero to turn off the FET. Nobody would ever rely on this circuit to work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A MOSFET does not suddenly turn on or off at the Vgs(th) value. Look more closely at the datasheet and it shows that at Vgs = -2V (the minimum), there is in fact 250 microamp of drain current (the test condition).

[image: Vgs with test condition]

What you are seeing is conduction in the [sub-threshold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subthreshold_conduction) region.

A zero current (or close to it) of -1.2V seems reasonable for a device rated at -2V.

You should always set Vgs to zero volts (for an enhancement mode device) to guarantee the part is fully turned off. The circuit below does the job. Note the control is inverted.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzmZ11.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edited for MKeith's comment.

Comment: For a newbie, this sentence might be a bit confusing: "You should always put the gate and source to zero volts." For the OP, you want to insure, somehow, that Vgs is zero when you want the FET to be off. Don't fool around with voltages anywhere near Vgs(th).

Comment: I edited the question accordingly, and added a schematic. Thanks!

Comment: @mkeith: I agree that operating a FET in the sub-threshold region is not recommended (and is usually undesirable, particularly in a switched application) although some interesting applications might use the effect to advantage.